# change colors in bar chart in r to other colors

Tags: r

I hopes you can assist me.
I made a bar chart in R of 3 bars. Now the bars are in grey, and I want to change them to other colors, but even when I write this in the code, the colors remain Grey.
Do you have any idea?

Thank you,

```
p<-ggplot(DATA.df, aes(x=sentiment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count")+theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red', 'purple', 'pink'))
p
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is because you are trying to use `scale_fill_manual` but don't have anything mapped to the `fill` aesthetic. Here is an example using the built-in `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count")+
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red', 'purple', 'pink'))
p
```